# Find the average of a column that meets criteria of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset and I need to use Python and Pandas to find the average prices of specific items in a column that meet specific criteria. The criteria are "Honda" and "Toyota" in the "manufacturer" column, "good" in the "condition" column, and "sedan" in the "type" column. The prices are in the "price" column. I would then need to return the specific values into a tuple.

I know I need to use groupby() but i'm not sure what else to do

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv("vehicles.csv")
def get_avg_prices():
df.groupby(['criteria','manufacturer','condition']).['price'].mean
```

This is how I started but not sure where to go from here or if this is right

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby(['criteria','manufacturer','condition'])['price'].mean()
```

This is the right Groupby function. you had an extra "." dot before ['price'] and you are missing a pair of parentheses ().
add this code after your dataframe

```
df = df[(df[ "manufacturer"]=="Honda") | (df[ "manufacturer"]=="Toyota") & (df[ "condition"]=="good") & (df[ "type"]=="sedan")]
df = df.groupby(['criteria','manufacturer','condition'])['price'].mean()
tuples = list(df.itertuples(index=False, name=None))
```

Comment: How would I get the specific values of the criteria returned to a tuple

Comment: Could you please give an example of the returned output wanted? you can get list of tuples by calling list function and passing the grouppedby dataframe to itertuples function. list(df.itertuples(index=False, name=None))

Comment: The returned output wanted would be a tuple of the value of the average price of the items that meets those criteria above